# Ubuntu Linux driver for My Passport Elite

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I have a new My Passport Elite and at first I could open it on my Ubuntu Linux laptop but I could not open it on Mac OS X.

Someone formatted it and now I could open it on Mac OS X and Windows XP but not on Ubuntu Linux any more. When I tried to open it on my Ubuntu Linux, it says there is an error.

What can I do to open it on all three systems just like my flash drive?

Comment: Do you know what they formatted it to? The only format that natively works across all three operating systems is FAT32.

Comment: I don't know anything about how he format it but is there any format that he can do so the Passport Elite can work with all three systems?

Answer (score 0):

Format (or have someone format) the drive to NTFS.

On Ubuntu and Windows XP, NTFS is both readable and writeable.

OS X *by default* is NTFS read-only.

To get around this limitation you can download the NTFS-3G package that enables writes to NTFS-formatted drives.

You can find it here: http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/

After you install NTFS-3G onto OS X, and format the drive to NTFS, you will be able to read and write files whether you are using Windows XP, Ubuntu, or OS X.

Answer (score 0):

Format your drive with FAT32 so that there is support across all 3 systems. FAT32 is both read/write capable with Windows XP, Ubuntu Linux, and Mac OS X.